# How to solve limits with these terms?

Tags: limits

Let *f* be such a function that $|f(x)|≤ x^2$ and 0 ≤ |x| ≤ 1.
How can I define $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$?

Comment: Or what about limit f(x)/x?

Comment: What do you mean by define? The limit of such a function is $0$ by squeezing.

Answer (score 1):

Your function must lie in the shaded region:

[image]

You can bound your function at $0$ from below and above by the quadratics.

Can you finish the steps from there?

Comment: David.Beautiful.